# How to access IBM Cloudant with Indy with Delphi 2009?

Tags: json, delphi, https, indy, cloudant

I want to use Delphi to create a doc in IBM Cloudant and if ok, PUT an attachment to that document.

I'm using a `.BAT` file for the moment that is executed from inside a Delphi application, but I would rather do it from Indy.

The `.BAT` file is as follows:

```
http -a 'user':'password' POST https://'user'-bluemix.cloudant.com <request.json >created.json
```

Then `status`, `id` and `rev` are extracted from `created.json` and if ok then the file is attached with:

```
http -a 'user':'password' PUT https://'user'-bluemix.cloudant.com/%id%/dbfile?rev=%rev% Content-Type:text/plain <dbfile7z.base64 >createdfileout.json
```

Can anybody give me some help? I have found examples, but I'm not able to get it working.

Comment: I just add that Cloudant has a [well described API](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html).

Comment: And there are numerous examples of posting data with Indy and HTTPS. So what is the actual problem you are having? Please show the actual code you are having trouble with, and explain why it is not working for you.

Comment: Bad target, [it's been moved](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/getting-started.html#getting-started-with-cloudant).

Comment: This is my first Indy project, and I didn't understand how to pass the request.json with the url. Now I see it is the http.RequestBody that carries the input. Changing my code, it worked! Thank you all, sorry to bother you.

Comment: @Bosse: there is no `http.RequestBody` in Indy. Data is posted by passing a `TStream` object (like `TFileStream`) to the `TIdHTTP.Post()` or `TIdHTTP.Put()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I was following an example at https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/indy-10-6-https-post/ and a variable http was declared as TidHTTP and RequestBody was declared as TStream and I was mislead that http.RequestBody was an Indy parameter. Si infact I used a Tstream Object and it worked.